# Send Keys with 10 second delay - C#

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I need to set a delay on the `SendKeys.Send` in my code. How can this be done?

```
case "Open Google Chrome":
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe");
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
break;
```

Why do I need this? **Due to my system being slow Google Chrome takes about 10 seconds to start up so essentially I need the delay for the `Sendkeys` to be set to 10 seconds because I want the key pressed after Google Chrome has loaded up.**

An example would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of sending the Enter key to Chrome at startup?

Comment: Be careful with `Thread.Sleep`, as on another system, or even your system under different load this may not fire when you expect it.

Comment: @Steve, I'm just using it as an example. :)

Comment: OK, but I have asked because if you need to force Chrome to do something when it is fully loaded perhaps it is better to explain your intentions. It is possible that other means exists (command line for example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just sleep in between the two actions.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple Google search would have turned up:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

But keep in mind that a far better approach would be to loop each second, checking if Chrome had actually started since this will better handle situations where:

1. Chrome startup suddenly gets faster (you won't then wait unnecessarily).
2. Chrome takes 11 seconds to start one day (your ten-second-delay script fails miserably).

Comment: Completely agree with you. But what about if the process has already started in Task Manager but just hasn't loaded on screen?

Comment: @Mohammed, why would you think an application needs to display something before its message pump is running? In any case, you can wait for a window to appear rather than a process to start.

Comment: I know, its a lil late and propably this will not be used anymore but i truly agree with paxdiablo and if you matter if the window is shown on screen than improve your application with `FindWindow(string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);` from `[DllImport("user32.dll")]` there you could check the if its there or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Thread.Sleep(10 * 1000);` but this will make current thread to sleep for 10seconds. If you dont want to make Current Thread to sleep I will suggest you to use a `Timer`

```
var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((x) =>
{
    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
}, null, 10000, Timeout.Infinite);
```

This will be executed in `ThreadPool` thread preventing your current thread from blocking.

Comment: I see oleksii has mentioned this aswell. What exactly does "Thread.Sleep" do? And is it better to use a Timer?

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` will make the current thread(Executing thread) to block for minimum given number of milliseconds. in your case Current thread will sleep minimum 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread.Sleep(10000)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx

(EDIT: removed CurrentThread reference as correctly pointed out in comments)

Comment: `Sleep()` is a static method.  You do not have to (and should not) use a particular instance of `Thread` to make use of it.

Comment: @cdhowie: And cannot, except in VB.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
Thread.sleep(10000) 
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}";
```

You use the 10000 because it is in milliseconds